# Blazor DropdDown menu item click event handling

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I created a dropdown component.I don't use javascript in this component.

When user clicks on dropdown, dropdownmenu shows. I have to do delay to catch click event of the menu items(Counter and Fetch Data in image).

If I remove delay, then blur or focusout events run before click event, so menu will close and click(redirection) will not happen.

The solution I found in the internet is adding a delay. But it is not What I want.
Is there any better solution? If I have to use delay, which is the way to compute delay time?

[image: DropDown Menu blazor component]

```
@if (Items != null)
{
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" @onclick="Show">
        <a class="nav-link @(Disabled?"disabled":"")" role="button">
            @Text
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu @(isVisible?"d-block":"d-none")" tabindex="-1" @onblur="Close" @ref="ddref">
            @Items
        </ul>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link @(Disabled?"disabled":"")" aria-current="page" href="@NavigateUrl">@Text</a>
    </li>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; } = "Menu Item";
    [Parameter] public string NavigateUrl { get; set; } = "#";
    [Parameter] public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;
    private ElementReference ddref;
    private bool isVisible = false;

    public void Show()
    {
        isVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public async void Close()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        isVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!firstRender)
            if (isVisible)
            {
                await ddref.FocusAsync();
            }
    }
}
```

NavBar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <CascadingValue Value="this">                    
                        @Items
                </CascadingValue>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public List<MLMenuItem> DropDownList { get; set; } = new List<MLMenuItem>();
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MLMenuItem ActiveDropDown { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Items { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
<MLMenu>
    <Items>
            <MLMenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="/" />
            <MLMenuItem Text="Link" NavigateUrl="Counter" />
            <MLMenuItem Text="DropDown" >
                <Items>
                    <MLMenuItem Text="Counter" NavigateUrl="counter" />
                    <MLMenuItem Text="Fetch Data" NavigateUrl="fetchdata" />
                </Items>
            </MLMenuItem>
            <MLMenuItem Text="DropDown">
                <Items>
                    <MLMenuItem Text="Counter" NavigateUrl="counter" />
                    <MLMenuItem Text="Fetch Data" NavigateUrl="fetchdata" />
                </Items>
            </MLMenuItem>
            <MLMenuItem Text="Disabled" Disabled=true />
    </Items>
</MLMenu>
```

Comment: if you replace delay with `await Task.Yield` does everything work as expected? My suspicion is that the solution is not dependent on the `Delay`. I  think the `await` is the key releasing the thread for re-rendering.

Comment: What I believe is happening is that without the `await Task.Delay(200)`, the item you are clicking on disappears and your click on thin air.  If you add the delay this delays the render that closes the menu long enough for the click event to be registered.  If you move the mouse very slowly does the click fail?  Can you put your NavBar code in the question along with any CSS to help in anyone making a suggestion.